# How to enable "try it" feature on Redoc page, as shown in the picture

Tags: drf-yasg, redoc

[image]
The image is from [here](https://silly-cat-58.redoc.ly/#tag/Test-API). (It is not my website.)

My backend framework is based on Django REST Framework.

I am able to use the "Try it" functionality in Swagger, but I don't really want to use it because Swagger does not support a left-hand side menu (which Redoc does support).

I have consulted the configuration [documentation](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#) related to drf_yasg, but I have not found any available configurations.

Comment: The "Try it" feature is in the Redocly hosted API reference docs product, but it isn't included in open source redoc.

Comment: See [docs](https://redocly.com/docs/api-reference-docs/guides/try-it-console/): "The Try it feature is not available in Redoc. You need access to Redocly API docs or Developer portal products to use the Try it feature."